# In Daniel 11:37, is it possible to translate god of his father with "god" lowercase in the singular form?

Tags: hebrew, daniel, names-of-god, masoretic-text

Neither shall he regard the God of his fathers, nor the desire of women, nor regard any god: for he shall magnify himself above all. (Daniel 11:37 - King James Version)

‎וְעַל־אֱלֹהֵ֤י אֲבֹתָיו֙ לֹ֣א יָבִ֔ין וְעַל־חֶמְדַּ֥ת נָשִׁ֛ים וְעַֽל־כָּל־אֱל֖וֹהַּ לֹ֣א יָבִ֑ין כִּ֥י עַל־כֹּ֖ל יִתְגַּדָּֽל׃
(Daniel 11:37 - Leningrad Codex)

I know that there is some verse in the Old Testament which contains the plural and the translation is not "God" in uppercase and neither "gods". For example 1 Kings 11:3, where we can find "god" and "goddess" translated from the plural construct.
Is it possible that the translation can be "god" lowercase in the singular form? Am I wrong or is it a matter of the accent < placed under the letter of the lemma "אֱלֹהֵ֤י" which makes the difference?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

Many versions translate אֱלֹהֵ֤י (plural) and אֱל֖וֹהַּ (singular) in Dan 11:37 with lower case, eg:

- NIV: He will show no regard for the **gods** of his ancestors or for the one desired by women, nor will he regard any **god**, but will exalt himself above them all.
- ESV: He shall pay no attention to the **gods** of his fathers, or to the one beloved by women. He shall not pay attention to any other **god**, for he shall magnify himself above all.
- BSB: He will show no regard for the **gods** of his fathers, nor for the one desired by women, nor for any other **god**, because he will magnify himself above them all.
- NASB: And he will show no regard for the **gods** of his fathers or for the desire of women, nor will he show regard for any other **god**; for he will boast against them all.
- CSB: He will not show regard for the **gods** of his ancestors, the god desired by women, or for any other **god**, because he will magnify himself above all.
- HCSB: He will not show regard for the **gods** of his fathers, the god longed for by women, or for any other **god**, because he will magnify himself above all.
- ASV: Neither shall he regard the **gods** of his fathers, nor the desire of women, nor regard any **god**; for he shall magnify himself above all.
- ISV: He'll recognize neither the **gods** of his ancestors nor those desired by women—he won't recognize any **god**, because he'll exalt himself above everything.
- ... + many more

I believe these versions are correct in so translating these Hebrew nouns.

Comment: I was only referring to the first term in the verse which the King James Version translates into "God" in uppercase. I wanted to know if this first term can be translated into "god" in lowercase.

Comment: @Relyze - the answer is yes as per my response above.

Comment: @Relyze - the first term is plural and when that does not refer to YHWH, it must be translated as plural.

Comment: Nope, because you referenced Bible verses that translate the first term into "gods" in the plural form. I knew that the first term can be translated into "gods" too.  The first term is plural construct, while the second one is singular absolute. I am only interested in the first term. Since the first term has that sign under one letter so as to differ from the plural constructs translated into "god" and "goddess" in 1 Kings 11:38, I was wondering if it is a matter of that sign which makes the difference so as that specific term in Daniel 11:37 cannot be translated as "god" in the singular form

Comment: Read the new comment. The old was too brief. As said in the question of my post too, in 1 Kings 11:33, for example, the plural is translated into "god" two times and one time into "goddess".

Comment: @Relyze - I stand by my last comment - when elohim does not refer to YHWH/Jehovah, it must be translated in the plural.

Comment: Dottard, I repeat that there are some cases where the plural is translated in the singular. Read the Hebrew text of 1 Kings 11:33 for example

Comment: @Relyze - then you should ask a question about that verse.  I would argue that they should be plural

Comment: + 1 I don't agree that "when elohim does not refer to YHWH/Jehovah, it must be translated in the plural," but I think your main answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Paul references this passage of Daniel and describes Emperor Titus:

> [2Th 2:1-12 NASB20] [1] Now we ask you, brothers [and sisters,] regarding the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ and our gathering together to Him, [2] that you not be quickly shaken from your composure or be disturbed either by a spirit, or a message, or a letter as if from us, to the effect that the day of the Lord has come. [3] No one is to deceive you in any way! For [it will not come] unless the apostasy comes first, **and the man of lawlessness is revealed, the son of destruction, [4] who opposes and exalts himself above every so-called god or object of worship, so that he takes his seat in the temple of God, displaying himself as being God.** [5] Do you not remember that while I was still with you, I was telling you these things? [6] And you know what restrains [him] now, so that he will be revealed in his time. [7] For the mystery of lawlessness is already at work; only He who now restrains [will do so] until He is removed. [8] Then that lawless one will be revealed, whom the Lord will eliminate with the breath of His mouth and bring to an end by the appearance of His coming; [9] [that is,] the one whose coming is in accord with the activity of Satan, with all power and false signs and wonders, [10] and with all the deception of wickedness for those who perish, because they did not accept the love of the truth so as to be saved. [11] For this reason God will send upon them a deluding influence so that they will believe what is false, [12] in order that they all may be judged who did not believe the truth, but took pleasure in wickedness.

For a full exposition from an NT perspective, please see:

https://www.revelationrevolution.org/2-thessalonians-2-1-9-a-preterist-commentary-the-man-of-lawlessness-revealed/

So to answer your question, yes, "gods" is the right idea.

Comment: I wanted to know if in the phrase "God of his fathers" that lemma can be translated into "god" as singular. Now I edited my post and it is more clear.

Comment: 37 Neither shall he regard the God of his fathers, nor the desire of women, nor regard any god: for he shall magnify himself above all. 38 But in his estate shall he honour the God of forces... (Daniel 11:37-38 - King James Version). The correct translation cannot be “gods” in the plural because in Daniel 11:38 the Hebrew text has “in his estate”. The subject to whom “in his estate” is referring to is necessarily “… of his fathers” in the verse 37. The question was if the correct translation must necessarily be "God" or there might be "god".

Answer (score 1):

To start, here is a typical translation of 1 Kings 11:33, which the OP rightly cites as a case where *elohim* is translated as the singular but uncapitalized "god."

> For they have forsaken me and have bowed down to Astarte, goddess of
> the Sidonians, Chemosh, god of Moab, and Milcom, god of the Ammonites.
> They have not walked in my ways or done what is right in my eyes,
> according to my statutes and my ordinances, as David his father did. (NABRE)

Here the reference is clearly to one deity in each case, so "god" is the correct translation. In the case of the OP's quote, we should consider the context. The preceding verse reads:

> 36 “The king shall do as he wills, exalting himself and making himself
> greater than any god; he shall utter dreadful blasphemies against the
> God of gods...

If, as many commentators believe, this is a reference to Antiochus IV Epiphanes, then the question becomes, does the "God of his ancestors" in vs. 37 refer to the Hebrew God, or to a pagan god/s?  We can rule out the former, so the OP's translation is wrong to capitalize "God."  A note in the NABRE version, which translates *elohim* as "gods" here, explains:

> Antiochus favored the cult of Zeus. Daniel takes this to imply the
> neglect of all other gods, although this does not appear to have been
> the case.

**In conclusion, although *elohim* may sometimes be correctly translated as either "god" or "gods" in this case the correct translation is "gods." In the OP's example "God" is wrongly translated because *elohim* here does not refer to the Hebrew deity.**

Comment: This conclusion would hold good even without the "Antiochus Epiphanes" interpretation, because the context of the entire chapter implies that the "kings of the north" are gentiles. So YHWH would not have been the God of his ancestors.